# Magento2 - dispatched event for create shipment

Tags: magento2, event-observer, di

I'm looking for similar event like `sales_order_shipment_save_after` and `sales_order_shipment_save_before` in Magento1.

Oh I am using Magento 2.1.3.

I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_before">
        <observer name="poczta_beforeshipment" instance="Test\Poczta\Observer\BeforeShipment" />
    </event>
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="pocztapolska_aftershipment" instance="Test\Poczta\Observer\AfterShipment" />
    </event>
</config>
```

But it is not working.
I tried find it here https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/
but I'm not sure what one is a correct.

Should I use observer via di instead event observer?
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-before-after-method-event-observer-using-plugin/

Comment: Your code should work, putting your event under `etc/adminhtml` folder: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

Comment: <facepalm>. It works fine right now. Thanks ;)

Comment: I leave my answer below. If it's helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, **putting your event under `etc/adminhtml` folder**: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`.