# Which event is used while submitting a shipment in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping

I need to execute my code after submitting shipment. I was using "**sales_order_shipment_track_save_after**" event in Magento 1.7 but it's not working with Magento 2.1.7 .

I have also tried some other event like "**sales_order_shipment_save_after**"  ,**sales_order_shipment_save_before** but didn't get success.

**event.xml in etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_before">
    <observer name="trackShiping" instance="Aftership\Track\Observer\Tracking"/>
  </event>
  <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_aftership_options">
    <observer name="index" instance="Aftership\Track\Observer\ChangedSection"/>
  </event>
</config>
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to answer in following thread. It is similar to your issue.

[Magento2 - dispatched event for create shipment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154246/magento2-dispatched-event-for-create-shipment)

Comment: Hello @kishan I have tried this too but not working in my case.

Comment: Wait I upload events.xml code

Comment: please take a look at events.xml what I am doing wrong @kishan

Comment: I realized my mistake actually I was not implementing observerInterface in my observer class that's why problem is coming.