# Magento 2 - Sales Order Shipment Event/Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipment

I search on the Internet for **sales order shipment event**. In many Stack Exchange question I found this event **`sales_order_shipment_save_after`**.

In most of Question they are saying it is not working and didn't even mark correct answer of that particular question.

When I search for the **Magento 2 event list**. I am unable to find **`sales_order_shipment_save_after`** this event.**So I need to know all Sales Order Shipment related events badly**.

Reference: https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-events-list/

Comment: You should try this solution : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187912/which-event-is-used-while-submitting-a-shipment-in-magento-2

Comment: @Aasim Thanks for the link much appreciated. I already saw this link and it's solution. That's why I am asking `sales_order_shipment_save_after` event **not found in event list.**

Comment: You can see in this question, this event is working: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154246/magento2-dispatched-event-for-create-shipment

Comment: @AasimGoriya That's why I am confused. Whether this event `sales_order_shipment_save_after ` is part of magento 2 events. So I am looking for all shipment related event. I hope you got my point

Comment: @Hasham because we can't trust on every blog posts, there are lots of event's available in magento, and not each blog have all data, they have added events what they known. so this might be possible if they missing something.

Comment: @AasimGoriya if you know any link which is valid and have all events related to sales order shipment please mention it on answer. I am eagerly looking for it that's the essence of this question. I need a list of all events related to sales order shipment.

Comment: Please check my ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of example of links for events lists but mostly I follow below link, it contain almost all events, and this blog has **`sales_order_shipment_save_after`** as well, so I hope it will help you.

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/list-of-all-events-in-magento-2/

Thanks :)

Comment: looks great. let me try this and come back to you with your score

Comment: Thanks @Aasimgoriya much appreciated Brother.

Comment: Pleasure bro :) Happy to help!