# How to set order status in magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status

I want to set orders status  **`pending`** in magento 2.4.

Please help me

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Is there any third party related to that installed?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $orderId = 1; // here order id

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId); 
$order->setState("pending")->setStatus("pending");
$order->save();
```

OR

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
){
    $this->order = $order;
}
public function updateorder(){
    $order = $this->order->load($orderId);
    $order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: i want to set orders status pending.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: online payment order status pending now working but after sometime how to set in processing status in admin side. Because in admin side not showing in options. So Please  help me how to set in processing admin sale > order > view

Comment: if this answer kindly upvote....and after sometime when you need to change status from pending to processing?

Comment: yes i have ship order but still status are showing pending.

Comment: create event observer when you ship the order in that observer put this code

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154246/magento2-dispatched-event-for-create-shipment use this for help